# Is it possible to make a sweet.js macro `m` expand to the symbol `m`?

Tags: sweet.js

Suppose there's a function somewhere called `m`, which is invoked like this

```
//foo.js
m("foo")
```

I have a sweet.js macro that defines a macro called `m` which is meant to take foo.js and expand `m` (basically to run the function at compile time)

In some cases I want to not expand `m`, because unlike macros, functions can be passed around as first class citizens

```
doSomething(m) //don't want to expand this as a macro
```

If I don't have a case that covers this scenario in the macro, sweet.js complains, so I need to have a catch-all rule that just expands to the same symbol.

```
macro m {
  //simplification to demonstrate a case that recursively expand macro
  case { _ ( $foo, $bar) } => { return #{m($foo)} }
  //does syntax unwrapping in real case
  case { _ ( $foo ) } => { return #{$foo} }

  //**this tries to recursively expand `m`, which is not what I want**
  case { _ } => { return #{m} } 
}
```

How do I make the `m` macro expand to the `m` function, given that other cases of the macro do need to recursively expand `m` as a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to `let` bind the macro:

```
let m = macro {
  case { _ ( $foo, $bar) } => { return #{$foo} }
  case { _ ( $foo ) } => { return #{$foo} }

  // `m` is bound to the surrounding scope, not the macro
  case { _ } => { return #{m} }
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, didn't read your question fully the first time :)

Here's a better solution, you just need to split it out into two different macros, one that can do the actual recursive work and another to handle the non-recursive base case:

```
function m() {}
macro m_impl {
  case { _ ( $foo, $bar) } => { return #{m_impl($foo)} }
  case { _ ( $foo ) } => { return #{$foo} }
}

let m = macro {
  case { _ ($foo, $bar) } => { return #{m_impl($foo, $bar)} } 
  case { _ } => { return #{m} } 
}

m (100, 200);
doSomething(m)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when some of the case rules do need to expand m as a macro (as in the first case)

Comment: Ah, sorry read your question too fast. Edited in what is hopefully a better solution for you.

Comment: You can also use `#{$[m]}` instead of using let.